# assign heights of cells from one list of tables to another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are several pairs of `<table>`s on the html page.

Each pair of tables have the same number of rows.

The first table of each pair has class `class1`.

The second table of each pair has class `class2`.

The problem is: each cell should have the same height in both tables.
How to make it with jQuery?

I'm thinking of using `.each` or `eq` or combination of both like:

```
$('table.class2 tr').each(function(i){
      ????? = $(this).height();//suppose height of cells in class2 is bigger or the same so we shouldn't care about finding max value and assigning to the `tr` with smaller height
});
```

As an option, `id`s or additional classess may be assigned (however I don't want to do that by some reason).

Any suggestions?
P.S. Also I believe if I do `$('table.class1 tr').each()` with `class1`, not `class2`, the order of rows in tables would be the same (checked in console).

It is OK if the height of cells in any table is variable. The only requirement is for each pair the height of first row is equivalent, the height of the second row is equivalent and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: You may conceder using an array to store row heights of `class1` with `each` and then have another `each` loop to set those stored heights to rows in `class2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```js
$('table.class2 tr').each(function(i){
  var $table1Elem = $('table.class1 tr').eq(i);
  if($table1Elem.height()>$(this).height()){
    $(this).height($table1Elem.height());     
  }else{
    $('table.class1 tr').eq(i).css('height',$(this).height());
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="float:left; width:49%;">
                <table class="class1">
                    <tr><td>text 1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>text<br><br>2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>text 3</td></tr>        
                </table>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width:49%;">
                <table class="class2">
                    <tr><td>text 1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>text 2</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>text <br><br>3</td></tr>        
                </table>
            </div>
```